# does intel Xeon e5620 have EPT support?

Tags: virtualization, xeon, 64-bit, intel-vt-x

looking for CPU with good Virtualization support. could not find Intel EPT (extended page table) technology with E series. Is it only with higher X series?

but AMD Magny cour 6134 does have the RVI support (Rapid Virt Indexing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, all Nehalem/Westmere chips support EPT, so that's the 55xx/56xx/75xx ones plus I'm sure the 35xx/36xx series too (sorry but I'm no expert at workstation chips).